# Printing support in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-webapi

My .net framework 4 service is using PrintDocument class of System.Drawing.Printing for printing.

How can I achieve this in .net core. I am not able to find System.Drawing.Printing in .net core.

Can someone guide me on this?

Answer (score 7):

.NET Core 3 supports `System.Drawing.Printing`

I have an app sorta working on Linux now. I'm experiencing some weirdness which led me to this question.

FWIW, my app is a pretty complete example of how to use the `System.Drawing.Printing` APIs. Find it here: https://github.com/tig/winprint

Comment: If you use System.Drawing in .NET CORE is it also possible to use System.Drawing.Printing in a Linux-Docker-Container?

Answer (score 6):

One option is to split monolithic service(s) into multiple microservices and run your .NET Core app under i.e. Linux and let your print service on windows and have the .NET Core service call into the print service when it needs to print something

Comment: This is exactly how I do it. Best of both worlds I guess

Answer (score 4):

System.Drawing is windows-dependent and excluded from cross-platform NETStandard libraries (not available for .NET Core apps).

As alternative you may consider composing PDF or PS document (for instance, wkhtmltopdf tool can convert HTML pages to PDF/PS formats) and sending it to printer with OS-specific command line tool (for linux this might be "lp" command; for windows PowerShell "lpr").

Comment: What? so you are telling me that an entire software development platform has no support for printing ? if so how is this even sane?

Comment: @docesam at this moment .NET Core is server-oriented platform (supports only web and console applications) and version 1.0 includes only API that is required for these application types (printing something on the server side is not typical task for web applications).

Comment: true, i am just venting emotions man because i think a cross platform framework should have all bells and whistles .

Comment: I used "lpr -S printer_ip -P printer_name -o l D:\\testpdf.pdf" command to print pdf on my windows machine, but it prints only garbage text. Can you tell me, what is wrong over here?

Comment: In Powershell 5 it seems that the command is `lp` as well, which is an alias for `Out-Printer`.